# Selenium IDE - how to run test suits automatically

Tags: selenium-ide

New to Selenium, and yes - was searching for the answer. 
Thanks in advance.

What is the best way to automate Selenium IDE?
I have made a set of test suits. Unfortunatelly running them one after another is a manual task - and frankly - I find it faster to just check the pages manually. Obvoiusly this is not the best usage of Selenium IDE.

So the question is: What is the best way you recommend to automate this process? And by BEST i mean: the easiest to understand and apply for a newbie. Any tool like PowerShell (if so - thanks for the script) or something? I do not care for the technology as much as I do care for the results.

Thanks again!

Regards,
GB

Comment: By Test Suites, you mean you have recorded manual testing steps through Slenium IDE and got a bunch of html files?

Comment: Something like that. Each Test Suite is made of about ~20 test cases ('html files'). 
I can open one test suit and run it. Then I need to open another one and run it...
And I have about 30 of them, finally I will be counting them in hundreds. I need a way to just run them automatically one by one without paying attention to anything else beside a summary report.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't have any other way. You just create a `heavy test suite`. But you need to add `some comment` between of your tests suite and test cases.